# TimeType styling

Tags: symfony, time, styles

I am trying to style my input field in Symfony 3.4 with symfony forms for some duration(hours and minutes only). I am trying with clockpicker but I don't know where I am wrong. If someone can help me or there is a better solution. I have downloaded and included my js and css in web folder.

I am trying to make it like this in the moment:

[image]

My twig:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
   <label for="time_for_cooking">Време за готвене(минути):</label>
      {% if form_errors(form.recipeCookingTime) %}
          {{ form_widget(form.recipeCookingTime, { 'attr': {'class': 'form- control clockpicker-control clockpicker is-invalid'} }) }}
              <div class="col">
                 <small  class="text-danger">
                     {{ form_errors(form.recipeCookingTime) }}
                 </small>
              </div>
      {% else %}
          {{ form_widget(form.recipeCookingTime, { 'attr': {'class': 'form control clockpicker-control clockpicker'} }) }}
      {% endif %}
</div>
```

My RecipeType.php

```
->add('recipeCookingTime', TimeType::class)
```

document ready

```
   <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        ('.clockpicker').clockpicker();
      } );
   </script>
```

and what its generated, I think the problem is these selects that being genereted

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your FormType you have to set the html5-attribute to false to get an input. 
See here https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/time.html#html5